# "omniaque perpeti ipsa" in De Finibus

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-identification, translation-explanation, cicero

In *De Finibus* 48, Cicero writes

> Qui ingenuis studiis atque artibus delectantur, nonne videmus eos nec valetudinis nec rei familiaris habere rationem omniaque perpeti ipsa cognitione et scientia captos et cum maximis curis et laboribus compensare eam quam ex discendo capiant voluptatem?

This all makes sense to me except *omniaque perpeti [ipsa]* (I put *ipsa* in brackets because I don't know whether it modifies *omnia* or *cognitione et scientia*.)

The translation in the Loeb edition reads

> Take persons who delight in the liberal arts and studies; do we not see them careless of health or business, patiently enduring any inconvenience when under the spell of learning and of science, and repaid for endless toil and trouble by the pleasure they derive from acquiring knowledge?

I would translate *omniaque perpeti ipsa* with something like "by everything continuous itself." This makes sense neither out of context (no great difficulty in Latin) nor in context.

How does *omniaque perpeti ipsa* function so that it can mean "patiently enduring any inconvenience"? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb [*perpeti*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1011952) means roughly "to endure patiently".
With the object *omnia* this seems to become "to endure anything patiently".
The Latin phrase is constructed with *accusativus cum infinitivo*, so a natural English translation would indeed be "patiently enduring any inconvenience".

You seem to have read *perpeti* as the ablative of *perpes*.
There does not seem to be a reasonable meaning with that reading.

I would consider *ipsa* to modify *cognitione et scientia* rather than *omnia*.

As TKR remarked in a comment, *omnia perpeti* looks like a calque of the common Greek phrase *hotioun pathein*, meaning basically the same ("to endure anything at all").